# How can I simplify this command in Linux consisting of cat piped to a grep?

Tags: linux, bash, grep, cat

How can I simplify this command in Linux consisting of `cat` piped to a `grep`.

```
cat foo*.txt | grep cow
```

I was told that this is the wrong way to do this. Why is that?

Comment: It is not as much 'wrong' as wasteful. This is gratuitous use of cat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass filenames to `grep`:

> grep cow foo*.txt

It's “wrong” because you're using `cat` when you don't need it, really.

Answer (score 3):

With respect for the work of the previous authors, I would point out that the two commands do (slightly) different things.  The OP's command concatenates all foo*.txt files, and searches the concatenated result **once** to see whether the string 'cow' appears.  @Patrice Levesque's command performs N searches, one for each of the N matching files.

While admittedly obscure and contrived, it is possible to create cases where the OP's command works and the non-gratuitous command fails:

```
$ for C in w c o; do printf '%s' "$C" > foo-$C.txt; done
$ grep cow foo*.txt
$ cat foo*.txt | grep cow
cow
$ rm foo*
$ printf "wilco" > foo-1.txt
$ cp foo-1.txt foo-2.txt
$ grep cow foo*.txt
$ cat foo*.txt | grep cow
wilcowilco
```

My point is that it may **not** be the wrong way to do it, depending on what it is that you're trying to do.

Comment: This is a very good answer.